# React data how to transfer other side ? Add drop

Tags: reactjs

I have add drop list but I dont know how to transfer other side what I have to do ? I am using react v 0.14

```
<div className="parent">
<div className="div1">
<div> <h4>Aktif Rol Listesi</h4> </div>
<Card className="admin_create_card" id="kryesore">
<ul>
<li> <button> Admin</button> </li>
<li> <button> User</button> </li>
<li> <button> Deneme</button> </li>
<li> <button> Denem1</button> </li>
</ul>
</Card>

</div>

<div className="div2"> 
<button><i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></button> <br/>
<button> <i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i> </button> 
</div>

<div className="div3">
<div> <h4>Seçilmiş Rol Listesi</h4> </div>
<Card className="admin_create_card" id="kryesore">
<ul>
<li> <button>Super Admin </button> </li>

</ul>
</Card>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this by multiple Solutions:

Solution 1:

Use two state variable list to save all types of buttons on the left side (Admin, User, ...) and on the right side. and save the selected Button in a state variable.
On Click of the Button to move left or right move the selected button to the left state variable list or to the right state variable list.

Solution 2:

Use Material UI Transfer List: [Docs](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/)

Solution 3:
Use some other NPM Packages:

- [react-virtualized-transfer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized-transfer)
- [react-dual-listbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dual-listbox)